# Android play store review notification

Tags: android, google-play

Is there a service that will notify me whenever a user post a review for my app that meets a pre-defined criteria (e.g. a one-star rating)?

Google did not lead to any results.

Comment: unfotunately, there aren't  a service like that

Comment: _Andlytics_ is pretty much the best we have...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no official API right now. But you can get notifications for changes in rating and download count on your device if you use the Andlytics app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.github.andlyticsproject 
(open source, available at GitHub).

Comment: Please report any issues at GitHub so we can fix them. https://github.com/AndlyticsProject/andlytics/issues

Comment: what if I don't have an Android phone?

Answer (score 22):

For all who is still looking for an answer. Now there is such an option. In your google play developer console go to "settings" -> "Email notifications"

Direct link is [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/138230?hl=en).

Comment: Links to potential solutions are always welcome, but please add some details for future visitors in case the link is no longer available.

Comment: Thanks!! Right Answer!

Comment: Thank you... Is it possible to send the notifications to multiple emails?

Answer (score 0):

**No, Google doesn't provide any such service.**

**Edit**

*I thought Google mails you when someone comment or give a review on an application. Anyways, I'm wrong then.*

Comment: What do you mean "get updates for it on your mail" .. will I get updates on user reviews??

Comment: Do you get mail when a user leaves a comment on your app or rate?

Comment: Nope .. I don't get a mail when users rate my app.